# Rounding decimals of an Index

Tags: r, indexing, rounding

I created a "trust in politics"-index by aggregating 5 variables, all of which measured some form of trust on a scale from 1-10.

```
attach(ess_variablen)   
aggr_trst <- (1/5)*(trst_prl+trst_leg+trst_part+trst_politic+trst_polit)
```

However, the results now contain 1 decimal, whereas I would like to round the numbers in order not to have any decimals in the index numbers.

I have not been able to find a work-around in order to round numerical values created by an index. Does anyone know how to achieve that? Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the programming language to the tags and show the value declaration so that the code can compile. I don't see any rounding happening that you are talking about.

Comment: I'm afraid I am very inexperienced in this matter (sorry!). I'm using R and the value is numeric, since all 5 variables go from 0-10. The data in my index is therefore numbers like 5.8, 3.2, etc. These are the numbers that I would like to round, 5.8 would become 6 and 3.2 would become 3.

Answer (score 0):

The `round()` function can be used to round to the nearest whole number when one uses 0 as the number of decimal places. The following example illustrates this by summing rows in a data frame of uniform random numbers.

```
set.seed(950141237)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20),nrow=5,ncol=4))
data
data$index <- round(rowSums(data),0) # round to 0 decimal places to obtain whole numbers
data
```

...and the output.

```
> set.seed(950141237)
> data <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20),nrow=5,ncol=4))
> data
      V1        V2         V3         V4
1 0.07515484 0.8874008 0.37130877 0.05977506
2 0.30097513 0.8178419 0.05203982 0.10694951
3 0.82328607 0.4182799 0.24034152 0.52173278
4 0.52849399 0.8690592 0.66814229 0.66475498
5 0.01914658 0.8322007 0.41399458 0.19649338
> data$index <- round(rowSums(data),0) # round to 0 decimal places to obtain whole numbers
> data
          V1        V2         V3         V4 index
1 0.07515484 0.8874008 0.37130877 0.05977506     1
2 0.30097513 0.8178419 0.05203982 0.10694951     1
3 0.82328607 0.4182799 0.24034152 0.52173278     2
4 0.52849399 0.8690592 0.66814229 0.66475498     3
5 0.01914658 0.8322007 0.41399458 0.19649338     1
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand this right... What does `runif(20)` stand for?

Comment: I created a sample data frame using 20 uniform random numbers runif(20), that I converted to a matrix and then to data frame.

Answer (score -1):

Edit : Seems previous solution did not works sorry for inconvenience

You can try the `ceiling()` and the `floor()` function depending of your needs

```
notRound <- (1/5) * (1.2+2.3+3.3)
print(notRound)
roundUp <- ceiling(notRound)
print(roundUp)
roundDown <- floor(notRound)
print(roundDown)
```

Snippet live if you want to try
http://rextester.com/WURVZ7294

Comment: Ok so if my index is called aggr_trst it would be

`Fix(aggr_trst)` 

Is that right?

Comment: Hmm if I use `Fix()` a new window pops up where the code begins with `structure(c(5.8, 0.4, etc.)` displaying the exact same numbers (with decimals) as before...

Is there maybe a specific package that I need to install in order to use this command?

Comment: Maybe its package related i have edited with a new funciton example that you can try live